# How do I transform a dataframe series into multiple lists?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python and have a data transformation question...

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

**State  City        Units**

CO     Denver      900

CO     Pueblo      300

NY     New York    4000

NY     Rochester   500

I'd like to transform it so that there is only 1 entry per state such as this:

**State Units**

CO [900, 300]

NY [4000, 500]

Any thoughts on how I can approach this? Thanks!

Comment: `df.groupby('State').Units.apply(list)`

Comment: You do realize that, by doing this, you lose the resolution of which specific *city* had this, right?  You're *sure* you want this?

Comment: Thanks @Psidom, works great

Comment: @Makoto that's correct, i wanted to aggregate at the state level